# Timeout/inefficiency error with "for" loop and array.reduce in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, optimization

Working through a codewars challenge `(Simple Fun #237: Suffix Sums)`, and while I'm passing all the tests it's giving me a time-out error. The challenge is to make a new array from a given one, where each index of the new array is the summation of that same index in the original to the end of the original array.

For an array `1, 2, 3, -6,` the output should be `0, -1, -3, -6.`

```
b[0]= 1 + 2 + 3 - 6 = 0  
b[1]=     2 + 3 - 6 = -1  
b[2]=         3 - 6 = -3  
b[3]=           - 6 = -6
```

My code is this

```
function suffixSums(a) {
 var res=[]
 for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
  var newarray=a.slice([i])
   res.push(newarray.reduce(function(acc, val){ return acc + val },0))
  }
  return res
}
```

Any clue what's up? I'm just learning still obviously, optimization is a whole new world for me

Comment: Hint: start at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wasting time because you calculate the sum of each items from scratch, you can start from the end of the array and accumulate the sum as you go:

```js
function suffixSums(a) {
    var res = [],
        sum = 0;                              // sum of items from end to the current index (initialized with 0)
    for(var i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {  // loop from the end
       sum += a[i];                           // add the current number to sum
       res[i] = sum;                          // add the sum to the result array at index i (this line could be changed to: res.unshift(sum);)
    }
    return res;
}

console.log(suffixSums([1, 2, 3, -6]));
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the commentary, that helps a lot. Default thinking is definitely left to right, didn't occur to me to switch it

Comment: @skdfsdfa You can do it left-to-right as well, you just have to substract the whole sum from every element

Comment: @Bergi left-to-right is undoable unless you already got the sum, in which case you'll have to loop the array twice.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir single-pass or double-pass doesn't make a difference for algorithmic complexity :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the successor of an item and add the actual value while iterating from the end.

```js
function suffixSums(a) {
    var i = a.length - 1;
    while (i--) {
        a[i] += a[i + 1];
    }
    return a;
}

console.log(suffixSums([1, 2, 3, -6]));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind changing the original array (Codewars doesn't mind):

```
function suffixSums(a) {
 for(var i = a.length - 2; i > -1; i--)
   a[i] += a[i+1];
 return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this job like;

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, -6],
    res = arr.reduceRight((r,n) => r[0] === void 0 ? [n] : [n+r[0]].concat(r),[]);
console.log(res);
```